# How do I create a 1x0..1 association in EF4 using Model-First approach?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Consider the following example model:

- **Person** has 0..1 User
- **User** has 1 Person

**Attempt 1:**

- I dragged an association from `Person` to `User` on the model designer.
- I fixed the cardinality to meet my needs (the default is 1xN)
- I generated the DDL from model

**Problem:**

- The output `User` table has a `Person_id` column with no unique constraint. That is, it's not a 1x1 relationship as many Users can reference the same Person. There must be something wrong here

**Attempt 2:**

- Dragged an association from Person to User on the model designer.
- Fixed the cardinality to meet my needs (the default is 1xN)
- Selected the association and clicked the `Referential Constraint` button on the properties window to edit the association
- Selected Person to be the Principal and User to be the Dependent type
- Chosen the `Principal Key` to be Id and the `Dependent Property` to be also Id (I've read somewhere that I should use the same key for both types)

**Problem:**

I run this code:

```
using (var context = new Locadora())
{
    User user = new User ();
    user.PasswordHash = "hash";
    user.Pessoa = new Person();
    user.Pessoa.Nome = "André";

    context.Usuários.AddObject(user);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

- SaveChanges triggers this exception:

> A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'Id'

So I am out of choices now. I don't know how to implement a 1x1 neither a 1x0..1 relationship in Entity Framework.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first attempt can't work because current EF version doesn't support Unique keys at all. Second approach doesn't work because you dependent entity can't have autogenerated key = `StoreGeneratedPattern` must be set to `None`.

Comment: You saved me several times today. Thank you